# In the first mission Crossfire, is it better to end the scene just before the starting player takes his turn?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

In the Crossfire mission, there are 3 scenes where you face off with N, N+1, and N+2 obstacles in turn.  The Crossfire card is drawn at the start of the turn of the player who started the game (not the player who started the scene necessarily). I.e., if there are 4 players, the crossfire is drawn every 4 turns, and if the scene ends after 3 turns, the crossfire isn't drawn until the **second** turn in the next scene.

Is it more advantageous to end scenes as soon as your team can or to align the ending of a scene with the drawing of a crossfire event?

The benefit of ending as early as possible is that you can have a number of turns with no crossfire event active, particularly useful when you have a fresh batch of obstacles that could be pressuring or hindering your team in any number of ways.

The benefit of waiting is that the scene you are wrapping up could be very light on obstacles and offer a few turns of low or zero damage where you could draw 2 cards into hands with 3 or less cards and potentially heal allies, buy cards (although arguably not a benefit since you buy cards at the end of the scene), etc.

I lean toward ending the scene as soon as possible as the unpredictability of the crossfire puts me on edge, but I find I'm very close to being on the fence when tempted with giving my hand an extra two cards.  Because cards are drawn after one's turn, there is very **little** unknown when the obstacles are revealed, so it seems pretty important to have at least 3-5 cards in your hand if possible when the obstacles are drawn. The greatest likelihood, I'm thinking, is that this is simply best a judgement call given the state of people's hand sizes and health levels when the end of a scene is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to start the next set of obstacles without having to deal with a new crossfire card can be an advantage. Not to mention the fact that having a few extra turns to work on them might allow you to eliminate them with minimal crossfire cards going into the discard pile which will help you in the long run as you will get fewer hard obstacles to deal with.